# How to setup different launch screen image for iPad portrait and landscape mode?

Tags: ios, ipad, launch-screen

I am working on an application which support L & P orientation. I have to setup different images for L & P Mode. I am using Xcode 15.

On launchScreen I am using one imageview and setting up the image( Regular * Regular)

Comment: There is a possibility but it is hacky. There an example on [github](https://github.com/jjochen/AdaptiveLaunchScreen) . If uses constraints and priorities.

Comment: What needs to be different on your Launch Screen? What do you expect to happen if the user launches your app *while rotating* the device? If the user launches your app in iPad multi-tasking mode, is it Landscape or Portrait?